# Unable to generate and import user certificate from ADCS in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ad-certificate-services, pki

We are using Certificate Based Authentication using ADCS. So in order for user to access an internal website, they need their own signed certificate.

With ADCS, the user gets their signed certificate in form of CRT files ( user1.crt ) which they can use to open the restricted websites.

When user tries to request a certificate from Chrome by clicking on "User Certificate" and clicking on Submit they get the following error. However for Firefox it works perfectly.

[image]

We ideally then go to Firefox or Safari to request a certificate and get a signed CRT file.

Importing the CRT files directly in Firefox and Safari seems to work perfectly however when we try to import it in Chrome , it gives error saying  : " Private Key is not associated ".

Is there any way to directly import the CRT files in Chrome similar to Firefox or Safari ?

Any help will be appreciated !  :)